# Wrong communication in web server using php(REST API)

Tags: php, json

I sent the JSON message to my web server using POST in postman. But the echo shows only GET and no message. I think the echo should show POST not GET. And the below code is working but the format is not JSON. Please see the image below:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; 
    $url = 'http://115.145.163.244:5851/TEST52.php';
    echo $method;
    echo "<br />\n";

    switch ($method) {
        case 'POST':
            $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        break;
        case 'GET':
            $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        break;
        case 'PUT':
            $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        break;
        case 'DELETE':
            $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        break;
    }
    echo ($input->data->ContextID); //it does not work
    print_r($input); //it does work. But not in JSON format
    ?>      
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode()` converts JSON into array. Therefore if you want to save JSON value to your variable `$input` use `json_encode()` instead and if it's already in JSON, you don't have to parse it at all.